# glmer predict: warning message about outcome variable not being a factor

Tags: r, predict, lme4

I have a mixed effect model with binomial outcome fitted with `glmer`. For plotting purposes I would like to predict population-level values for a small dataset.

Below is an example illustrating my approach:

```
silly <- glmer(Sex ~ distance +age + (1|Subject), data=Orthodont, family=binomial)

sillypred <- expand.grid(distance=c(20, 25), age=unique(Orthodont$age))
sillypred$fitted <- predict(silly, sillypred, re.form=NA, type="response")
```

I get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In model.frame.default(delete.response(Terms), newdata, na.action = na.action,  :
  variable 'Sex' is not a factor
```

However, when I check, it looks like it is:

```
str(Orthodont["Sex"])
```

The variable `fitted` is still created  and the values make sense, but I'm curious about this message. Is there something I should be concerned about? Otherwise, what is the purpose of this message.

It might seem like a trivial question (after all, it all seems to work), in which case I apologize, but I want to make sure that I don't overlook something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a harmless bug that will always occur when predicting from a model with a factor response (the problem is that we use the `xlev` argument to `model.frame` including the levels of the response variable).  I've posted this at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/205 . Thanks for the report!

You could either ignore the warning or coerce the response variable to a binary value (which will give identical results).